# How to initialize array from array in zsh?

Tags: zsh

My script `test.zsh`:

```
args=$@
argss=($@)
echo ${@:2}
echo ${args:2}
echo ${argss:2}
```

The output:

```
$ ./test.zsh foo bar foobar
bar foobar
o bar foobar
o
```

It looks like `args` is being initialized as the string of `$@` instead of as an array. How do I initialize `args` as an array? `($@)` does not seem to work either

Comment: There is never any reason to write `args=$@`. It gives you a flat string, in which case you should use `args=$*` anyway.

Comment: What version of zsh are you using, and what options do you have set (`setopt` will print anything different from the default)? On 5.8.1 and without `ksharrays` or `shwordsplit`, `echo ${argss:2}` prints `foobar`.

Comment: Add a hashbang to the top of the shell script: `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`. Otherwise you'll get the default shell, e.g. `sh` on most macs.

Comment: Brackets and the shebang line made the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around `$@` to make `args` an array:

```
args=($@)
```

In other shells, you should also put quotes around it (`args=("$@")`) to avoid word splitting, but this is disabled by default in zsh (see the option `SH_WORD_SPLIT`).

Note that `${@:2}` will give you `$1 $2 $3 ...`, while `${args:2}` will give `$2 $3 ...`, because zsh prepends `$0` to `$@` when you use that form of parameter subscripting for compatibility with other shells.
The preferred zsh way to subscript arrays is `${arr[start,end]}`, where `end` is inclusive and may be negative.
`${args[1,-1]}` and `${args[@]}` will expand to the same thing.